# web3 library not sending data. Transaction failed

Tags: ethereum, blockchain, solidity, web3js, truffle

i am using a the latest npm version of web3 and when i try to send a data an error occurs. Transaction failed. if i downgrade my web3 version to 1.2.2 my transaction works successfully.

```
    import Web3 from "web3";
    
    const getWeb3 = () => { return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => { try { // Modern dapp browsers... if (window.ethereum) { const web3 = new Web3(window.ethereum);    
    
    // Request accounts using eth_requestAccounts
        await window.ethereum.request({ method: "eth_requestAccounts" });
    
        // Accounts are now exposed
        resolve(web3);
      }
      // Legacy dapp browsers...
      else if (window.web3) {
        // Use Mist/MetaMask's provider.
        const web3 = new Web3(window.web3.currentProvider);
        console.log("Injected web3 detected.");
        resolve(web3);
      }
      // Fallback to localhost; use dev console port by default...
      else {
        const provider = new Web3.providers.HttpProvider(
          "http://127.0.0.1:7545"
        );
        const web3 = new Web3(provider);
        console.log("No web3 instance injected, using local web3.");
        resolve(web3);
      }
    } catch (error) {
      reject(error);
    }});};
    export default getWeb3;
```